# i want to filter the password by javascript but when i use that code it pop up just the alert whatever the pwd i put

Tags: javascript, regex, html

```js
function check() {
  var passwd = document.getElementById('pass');
  if (passwd.length >= 8 && passwd.length <= 20 && !(/(.)\1{3}/i.test(passwd)) && (/[^A-Za-z]/.test(passwd)) && !(/0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|7890|8901|9012/.test(passwd)) && !(/qwer|wert|erty|rtyu|tyui|yuio|uiop|asdf|sdfg|dfgh|fghj|ghjk|hjkl|zxcv|xcvb|cvbn|vbnm|QWER|WERT|ERTY|RTYU|TYUI|YUIO|UIOP|ASDF|SDFG|DFGH|FGHJ|GHJK|HJKL|ZXCV|XCVB|CVBN|VBNM/.test(passwd)) && !(/\s/.test(passwd)) && !(/access14|americanidol|baseball|baseball1|bigdaddy|blink182|butthead|cocacola|computer|corvette|cowboys|danielle|dolphins|einstein|firebird|football|football1|iloveyou|iloveyou1|internet|jennifer|jordan23|liverpool|liverpool1|marlboro|maverick|melanie|michelle|midnight|mistress|mountain|myspace1|password|password1|princess1|qwertyui|redwings|rush2112|samantha|scorpion|slipknot1|srinivas|startrek|starwars|sunshine|superman|superman1|swimming|trustno1|victoria|whatever|passwort|passwort1|frankfurt|fussball/i.test(passwd))) {

    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Some of your information are incorrect");
    return false;

  }
}
```

```html
<input id="pass" type="text" />
<button onclick="console.log(check())">Check</button>
```

Comment: Even if you get the answer (`.value`), what is the point in this validation?

Answer (score 4):

This is because in your code, you are setting `passwd` to the `input` element:

```
var passwd = document.getElementById('pass');
```

You need to set it to the *value* of the `input` element:

```
var passwd = document.getElementById('pass').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change this line

`var passwd = document.getElementById('pass');`

With this:

`var passwd = document.getElementById('pass').value;`

Because in the other case you will always get the input node, not it's value (what you really want).

Hope it helps.